# Preview timed out while rendering the layout. This typically happens when there is an infinite loop or unbounded recursion in one of the custom views

Tags: android

why i have not a mobile interface here [Rendering Problems Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1zjP.jpg)
anyone answer me please :(

Comment: Weclome to StackOverflow! Can you add some source code to your question? I think it'll easier to understand with a description what you are trying to do and a clear question.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Click on the **AppTheme** or whatever you have

[image]

Then try the **Holo light** theme.